# U8glib funny problem

Tags: arduino-uno, u8glib, print

I have strange problem with u8glib library. I have code:

```
void void_Menu_draw_func_men()
{
  if ( menu_redraw_required != 0 ) {
   u8g.firstPage();
    do  {
     Menu_draw_func_men();
   } while( u8g.nextPage() );
   menu_redraw_required = 0;
  }
}

void Menu_draw_func_men()
{

  u8g.setFont(u8g_font_6x13);
  u8g.drawStr(30, 0, "Funkcje");
  u8g.drawStr(15, 15, "Zerowanie modulu");
  u8g.drawStr(15, 30, "Modul na max");
  if(menu_pos == 0){u8g.setCursorFont(u8g_font_cursor); u8g.setCursorStyle(144); u8g.enableCursor(); u8g.setCursorPos(10,20);}
  if(menu_pos == 1){u8g.setCursorFont(u8g_font_cursor); u8g.setCursorStyle(144); u8g.enableCursor(); u8g.setCursorPos(10,35);}
  u8g.setPrintPos(5, 50); u8g.print("R:  "); u8g.print(pot_R , 2); u8g.print("   L:  "); u8g.print(pot_L , 2);

  Serial.println("func md");//just for check...

}
```

And oled display shows only cursor and I can move that cursor as I change menu_pos value. **But no letters or values are printed on screen.** Only cursor...

If I copy and paste only code from void Menu_draw_func_men(); to other part of my program:

```
void void_Menu_draw_test_man()
{
  if ( menu_redraw_required != 0 ) {
   u8g.firstPage();
    do  {
     Menu_draw_test_man();
   } while( u8g.nextPage() );
   menu_redraw_required = 0;
  }
}
void Menu_draw_test_man()
{

  u8g.setFont(u8g_font_6x13);   //replace this dwo lines
  u8g.drawStr(0, 0, "wykonywanie tefsdfs man...");

}
```

Everything works perfect... I was trying to change void name, and I don't know where is problem...
This is on Arduino Uno; I have 66% used of program memory, and 60% used of dynamic memory.
Maybe you have some idea?...

Answer (score 1):

Your `void_Menu_draw_test_man()` function checks `menu_redraw_required`

Does your other part of the program update that variable? Do you call `void_Menu_draw_test_man()` from the `loop()` function?

It may help if you show the complete code, rather than small segments, since there are variables, such as `menu_redraw_required`, which are not changed anywhere in what is visible.

Note also that u8glib is no longer updated in favor of [u8g2](https://github.com/olikraus/u8g2/wiki)

Comment: I will check u8g2 library, maybe my u8glib couse problem...

Comment: about loops, I have while functions till i press back button, and then I back to main menu. It work fine

Answer (score 0):

`menu_redraw_required` is in every code segment, but all segments are in while loop, there is no chance to update `menu_redraw_required` in different part code... My code is quite big now... but, when I enter to `Menu_draw_func_men()`, cursor is turned on, I can move it. I also add `Serial.print();` to be sure that I enter to this `void Menu_draw_func_men();`. And I have always receive in console, a confirmation.

This is how I enter to selected screen from main menu:

```
if (digitalRead(KEY_SELECT) == LOW)
  {
    in_mmenu = false;

    switch(menu_current)
    {
      case 0:
        menu_redraw_required = 1;
        key_choose();
        break;
      case 1:
        menu_redraw_required = 1;
        test_auto();
        break;
      case 2:
        menu_redraw_required = 1;
        test_man();
        break;
      case 3:
        menu_redraw_required = 1;
        pot_read_menu();
        break;
      case 4:
        menu_redraw_required = 1;
        other_options(); **//previously i was function_menu**
        break;
    }
```

All screen works properly on almost the same code, only last screen on menu have problem...

See pictures how it looks. I also add code to "wybor klucza" menu. Just print part.
[image]

How I enter to void_Menu_draw... works fine in others screens. Just small part for entering methode.

```
 if(digitalRead(KEY_NEXT) == LOW)
{unit++; if(unit >= UNIT_ITEMS + 1)
{unit = 1;} 
menu_redraw_required = 1; void_Menu_draw_keyMenu(); delay(200);}
```

and

```
void void_Menu_draw_keyMenu()
{
  if ( menu_redraw_required != 0 ) {
   u8g.firstPage();
    do  {
     Menu_draw_keyMenu();
   } while( u8g.nextPage() );
   menu_redraw_required = 0;
  }
}
void Menu_draw_keyMenu()
{

  u8g.setFont(u8g_font_6x13);
  u8g.drawStr(30, 0, "Wybor klucza");
  u8g.drawStr(15, 15, "Zespol:  "); u8g.drawStr(60, 15, menu_unit_num[unit - 1]);
  u8g.drawStr(15, 30, "Numer mod:  ");  u8g.drawStr(78, 30, menu_mod_num[module - 1]);
  u8g.drawStr(8, 50, "Modul to 2 silniki!");
  if(menu_pos == 0 && in == false){u8g.setCursorFont(u8g_font_cursor); u8g.setCursorStyle(144); u8g.enableCursor(); u8g.setCursorPos(10,20);}
  if(menu_pos == 1 && in == false){u8g.setCursorFont(u8g_font_cursor); u8g.setCursorStyle(144); u8g.enableCursor(); u8g.setCursorPos(10,35);}
  if(menu_pos == 0 && in == true){u8g.setCursorFont(u8g_font_cursor); u8g.setCursorStyle(148); u8g.enableCursor(); u8g.setCursorPos(110,20);}
  if(menu_pos == 1 && in == true){u8g.setCursorFont(u8g_font_cursor); u8g.setCursorStyle(148); u8g.enableCursor(); u8g.setCursorPos(110,35);}

}
```

[image]

I show you 2 more codes. There are the same, this one void_Menu_draw_test_man works, this one Menu_other_options not. Notice that I change name from functions_men to other_option, just to be sure that name don't cause this issue. I aleso update u8glib to last version. I try use u8g2 library but i will have to change almost everything...

```
void test_man()
{
  menu_redraw_required = 1; void_Menu_draw_test_man();
  while(digitalRead(KEY_BACK) == HIGH)
  {
    if(digitalRead(KEY_PREV) == LOW){menu_pos = 1; menu_redraw_required = 1; void_Menu_draw_test_man(); delay(200);}
    if(digitalRead(KEY_NEXT) == LOW){menu_pos = 0; menu_redraw_required = 1; void_Menu_draw_test_man(); delay(200);}
  }
  menu_redraw_required = 1;
  u8g.disableCursor();
  in_mmenu = true;
}

void void_Menu_draw_test_man()
{
  if ( menu_redraw_required != 0 ) {
   u8g.firstPage();
    do  {
     Menu_draw_test_man();
   } while( u8g.nextPage() );
   menu_redraw_required = 0;
  }
}
void Menu_draw_test_man()
{

  u8g.setFont(u8g_font_6x13);
  u8g.drawStr(40, 0, "Funkcje");
  u8g.drawStr(15, 15, "Zerowanie modulu");
  u8g.drawStr(15, 30, "Modul na max");
  if(menu_pos == 0){u8g.setCursorFont(u8g_font_cursor); u8g.setCursorStyle(144); u8g.enableCursor(); u8g.setCursorPos(10,20);}
  if(menu_pos == 1){u8g.setCursorFont(u8g_font_cursor); u8g.setCursorStyle(144); u8g.enableCursor(); u8g.setCursorPos(10,35);}
  u8g.setPrintPos(5, 50); u8g.print("R:  "); u8g.print(pot_R , 2); u8g.print("   L:  "); u8g.print(pot_L , 2);

}
```

and second

```
void other_options()
{
  menu_redraw_required = 1; void_Menu_other_options();
  while(digitalRead(KEY_BACK) == HIGH)
  {
    if(digitalRead(KEY_PREV) == LOW){menu_pos = 1; menu_redraw_required = 1; void_Menu_other_options(); delay(200);}
    if(digitalRead(KEY_NEXT) == LOW){menu_pos = 0; menu_redraw_required = 1; void_Menu_other_options(); delay(200);}
  }
  menu_redraw_required = 1;
  u8g.disableCursor();
  in_mmenu = true;
}

void void_Menu_other_options()
{
  if ( menu_redraw_required != 0 ) {
   u8g.firstPage();
    do  {
     Menu_other_options();
   } while( u8g.nextPage() );
   menu_redraw_required = 0;
  }
}
void Menu_other_options()
{

  u8g.setFont(u8g_font_6x13);
  u8g.drawStr(40, 0, "Funkcje");
  u8g.drawStr(15, 15, "Zerowanie modulu");
  u8g.drawStr(15, 30, "Modul na max");
  if(menu_pos == 0){u8g.setCursorFont(u8g_font_cursor); u8g.setCursorStyle(144); u8g.enableCursor(); u8g.setCursorPos(10,20);}
  if(menu_pos == 1){u8g.setCursorFont(u8g_font_cursor); u8g.setCursorStyle(144); u8g.enableCursor(); u8g.setCursorPos(10,35);}
  u8g.setPrintPos(5, 50); u8g.print("R:  "); u8g.print(pot_R , 2); u8g.print("   L:  "); u8g.print(pot_L , 2);

}
```